# How can i run a script before destroy a docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need the run a shell script before destroy a docker container.But this script should not work when this container stopped.Only run when i destroy and rm this container.How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible. Have a look at this issue for more information: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6982

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not possible at the moment, you could use a workaround:

```
alias "docker-destroy"="<run-script> && docker rm"
```

For example:

```
alias "docker-destroy"="echo 'test' && docker rm"
```